# Returning a value from a modal tableview to the main tableview in swift (IOS)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a main viewController with a tableview. When a button is pressed on a cell, a modal will appear and allow user to select multiple selection. So I presented a modal controller which is again a tableViewController which on dismiss will give a string value. But once modalView is dismissed and returns to my main tableView, tableView.reload() shows Nil while unwrapping an optional value.

Code :

```
// In modalTableViewController
//Protocol
protocol modalViewControllerDelegate {
func sendText( text: String)
}

//after all cell operations Done Button Action
@IBAction func doneBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    mystr = selectedValues.joined(separator: ",")
    if(mystr != "")
    {
        let vc = viewController()
        delegate?.sendText(text: self.mystr)
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
//In viewController
class ViewController : UIViewController,modalViewControllerDelegate{
 func sendText(text: String) {
    saveFormValue(mystr: text)
}
// .....
//SaveFunction
func saveFormValue(mystr:String){
self.tableView.reloadData() //HERE IAM GETTING ERROR (FOUND NIL)
//save operations goes here

}


.....
///
//Checking Cell type and calling function
if (cell.type == .multiSelect) {
    showCheckBox(data: ["One","Two","Three"])       
}
// Modal view function
func showCheckBox(data:[String])
{
    print("ShowCheckBox")
    checkBoxData = data //Assigning to a globalVariable
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "multiselectSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: this seems like your tableView is nil. Have you connect the tableView yo your 'ViewController' as an outlet and implement `UITableViewDataSource`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you allocating the mainVC as the modal's delegate? I believe that is the step you are missing (based on the code posted)

If you are, you might want to add breakpoints and check that the `sendText` and `saveFormValue` methods are actually getting called.

Comment: You're right.. **sendText** is not invoked. what line should I include in my code ? I have a confusion there...